# How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?

Tags: postgresql, sorting, array, parse

Given the string:

> 'I think that PostgreSQL is nifty'

I would like to operate on the individual words found within that string. Essentially, I have a separate from which I can get word details and would like to join an unnested array of that string on this dictionary.

So far I have:

```
select word, meaning, partofspeech
from unnest(string_to_array('I think that PostgreSQL is nifty',' ')) as word
from table t
join dictionary d
on t.word = d.wordname;
```

This accomplishes the fundamentals of what I was hoping to do, but it does not preserve the original word order.

Related question:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8760419/251174)

Comment: Do you want to process *one* string or a whole *table of strings*? If so, does the table have a primary key?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter one string in a table (that does have a primary key)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### `WITH ORDINALITY` in Postgres 9.4 or later

The query can now simply be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('I think Postgres is nifty', ' ') WITH ORDINALITY x(word, rn);
```

Or, applied to a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t, regexp_split_to_table(t.col, ' ') WITH ORDINALITY x(word, rn);
```

Details:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

About the implicit `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=85d654bac90fe7dccbb0e7b3746870c2)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c097a/1)</sub>

### Postgres 9.3 or older - and more general explanation

#### For a single string

You can apply the window function [**`row_number()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to remember the order of elements. However, with the usual `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col)` you get numbers according to the *sort order*, not the **original position** in the string.

You could simply omit `ORDER BY` to get the position "as is":

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn
FROM   regexp_split_to_table('I think Postgres is nifty', ' ') AS x(word);
```

Performance of `regexp_split_to_table()` degrades with long strings.  `unnest(string_to_array(...))` scales better:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn
FROM   unnest(string_to_array('I think Postgres is nifty', ' ')) AS x(word);
```

However, while this *normally works* and I have never seen it break in simple queries, Postgres asserts nothing as to the order of rows without an explicit `ORDER BY`.

To **guarantee** ordinal numbers of elements in the original string, use [`generate_subscript()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) (improved with comment by @deszo):

```
SELECT arr[rn] AS word, rn
FROM   (
   SELECT *, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS rn
   FROM   string_to_array('I think Postgres is nifty', ' ') AS x(arr)
   ) y;
```

#### For a table of strings

Add `PARTITION BY id` to the `OVER` clause ...

Demo table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE strings(string text);
INSERT INTO strings VALUES
  ('I think Postgres is nifty')
, ('And it keeps getting better');
```

I use `ctid` as ad-hoc substitute for a *primary key*. If you have one (or *any unique column*) use that instead.

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ctid) AS rn
FROM  (
   SELECT ctid, unnest(string_to_array(string, ' ')) AS word
   FROM   strings
   ) x;
```

*This* works without any distinct ID:

```
SELECT arr[rn] AS word, rn
FROM  (
   SELECT *, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT string_to_array(string, ' ') AS arr
      FROM   strings
      ) x
   ) y;
```

#### Answer to question

```
SELECT z.arr, z.rn, z.word, d.meaning   -- , partofspeech -- ?
FROM  (
   SELECT *, arr[rn] AS word
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS rn
      FROM  (
         SELECT string_to_array(string, ' ') AS arr
         FROM   strings
         ) x
      ) y
   ) z
JOIN   dictionary d ON d.wordname = z.word
ORDER  BY z.arr, z.rn;
```

Comment: You can also exploit Pg's quirky SRF-in-SELECT-list behaviour: `SELECT generate_series(1,array_length(word_array,1)), unnest(word_array) FROM ....`. 9.3's `LATERAL` might provide nicer solutions to this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't `generate_subscripts(arr, 1)` work instead of `generate_series(1, array_upper(arr, 1))`?  I'd prefer the former for clarity.

Comment: @dezso: Good point. Simplifies the query some more. I amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Erwin have you seen this [WITH ORDINALITY post](http://www.depesz.com/2013/07/30/waiting-for-9-4-add-sql-standard-with-ordinality-support-for-unnest-and-any-other-srf/) from depesz?

Comment: @JackDouglas: As it happens, we had [a discussion about a related topic on Friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059654/return-list-with-dates-within-a-specified-range-from-a-single-query/19059726#19059726), which lead me to a similar discovery. I added a bit to the answer.

Comment: The link for "details" just links to this same page.  That's confusing.

Comment: @Wildcard: Confusing indeed, thanks for pointing out. I replaced it with a link to actual details and updated some details