# How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, array, json

I have a column `data` of type `json` that holds JSON documents like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "tags": ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

I would like to turn the nested `tags` array into a concatenated string (`'foo, bar'`). That would be easily possible with the `array_to_string()` function in theory. However, this function does not accept `json` input. So I wonder how to turn this JSON array into a Postgres array (type `text[]`)?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

### Postgres 9.4 or newer

[Inspired by this post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CABRT9RBTKzSWvuwd7ztXx=b7Sh0Z4gutdXPeE=j30sfV5acCMA@mail.gmail.com#CABRT9RBTKzSWvuwd7ztXx=b7Sh0Z4gutdXPeE=j30sfV5acCMA@mail.gmail.com), Postgres 9.4 added the missing functions to unnest JSON arrays.
<sub>[Thanks to Laurence Rowe for the patch and Andrew Dunstan for committing!](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/52E7C9C8.9080000@dunslane.net#52E7C9C8.9080000@dunslane.net)</sub>

- [**`json_array_elements_text(json)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)
- [**`jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Use [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) or an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) to build a Postgres **array** (type `text[]`) from the resulting set of `text`.
Or [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to build a string with a list of values (type `text`).

Focusing on **array** output (`text[]`), not string (`text`). Important **difference**: `null` elements are preserved in actual *arrays*. This is not possible in a string, which cannot contain `null` values. The **true representation** is an array.

Replace 'jsonb' with 'json' for type `json` in all following SQL code.

### TLDR: Use a custom function

Encapsulate the logic in a function for repeated use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js))';
```

In Postgres 14 or later, consider the new SQL standard form:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js));
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

Call (same for either function):

```
SELECT tbl_id, jsonb_array_to_text_array(data->'tags')
FROM   tbl;
```

- **`LANGUAGE sql`** for the simple function. (Fastest in my latest tests with Postgres 14.)
- **`IMMUTABLE`** (because it is) to avoid repeated evaluation in bigger queries and allow its use in index expressions.
- **`STRICT`** to return `null` for `null` input. Also: faster. The function cannot be [*inlined*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684) anyway because of the ARRAY constructor / the aggregate function, so `STRICT` cannot harm that.
- **`PARALLEL SAFE`** (in **Postgres 9.6** or later!) to allow parallel execution in big queries. See:

  - [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251274/when-to-mark-functions-as-parallel-restricted-vs-parallel-safe)

This function with a `STRICT` modifier is also as **true to the original** as possible in that it returns `null` for `null` input and an empty array for empty array input. Better than all of the below queries.

For completeness: use [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) for the reverse SQL array → `jsonb` conversion.

### Various solutions, step-by-step

Immediately aggregate **per row** in a `LATERAL` or correlated subquery, then **original order** is preserved and we don't need `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` or even a unique key in the outer query. See:

- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213592/how-to-apply-order-by-and-limit-in-combination-with-an-aggregate-function/213724#213724)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)
- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213592/how-to-apply-order-by-and-limit-in-combination-with-an-aggregate-function/213724#213724)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Basic query, returns `null` for empty array or `null` input:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, d.txt_arr
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(d.elem) AS txt_arr
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') AS d(elem)
   ) AS d;
```

Short syntax, returns `null` for empty array or `null` input:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, d.txt_arr
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(value) AS txt_arr
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')  -- default name is "value"
   ) d;
```

Shorter (and faster) with ARRAY constructor, returns empty array for empty array or `null` input:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, t.data->'tags' AS jsonb_arr, d.txt_arr
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags'))
   ) d(txt_arr);
```

Even shorter (and faster) with correlated subquery, returns empty array for empty array or `null` input:

```
SELECT tbl_id, ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')) AS txt_arr
FROM   tbl t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=04c1a2029e9f7c9266d54850e947629c)*

All of the above preserve original order of elements.

### Postgres 9.3 or older

Use the function [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). But we get **double quoted strings** from it.

Alternative query with aggregation in the outer query. `CROSS JOIN` removes rows with missing or empty arrays. May also be useful for processing elements. We need a unique key to aggregate:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, string_agg(d.elem::text, ', ') AS list
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(t.data->'tags') AS d(elem)
GROUP  BY t.tbl_id;
```

ARRAY constructor, still with quoted strings:

```
SELECT tbl_id, ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements(t.data->'tags')) AS quoted_txt_arr
FROM   tbl t;
```

Note that `null` is converted to the text value "null", unlike above. Incorrect, strictly speaking, and potentially ambiguous.

Poor man's unquoting with `trim()`:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, string_agg(trim(d.elem::text, '"'), ', ') AS list
FROM   tbl t, json_array_elements(t.data->'tags') d(elem)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Retrieve a single row from tbl:

```
SELECT string_agg(trim(d.elem::text, '"'), ', ') AS list
FROM   tbl t, json_array_elements(t.data->'tags') d(elem)
WHERE  t.tbl_id = 1;
```

Strings form correlated subquery:

```
SELECT tbl_id, (SELECT string_agg(trim(value::text, '"'), ', ')
                FROM   json_array_elements(t.data->'tags')) AS list
FROM   tbl t;
```

ARRAY constructor:

```
SELECT tbl_id, ARRAY(SELECT trim(value::text, '"')
                     FROM   json_array_elements(t.data->'tags')) AS txt_arr
FROM   tbl t;
```

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b6e6e50a4e00c548942ffa522fd206e5) here
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66495/5)</sub>

Related:

- [Need to select a JSON array element dynamically from a PostgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27957152/939860)

#### Original notes (outdated since pg 9.4)

We would need a ***`json_array_elements_text(json)`***, the twin of `json_array_elements(json)` to return proper `text` values from a JSON array. But that seems to be missing from the [provided arsenal of JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Or some other function to extract a `text` value from a scalar `json` value. I seem to be missing that one, too.
So I improvised with `trim()`, but that ***will fail for non-trivial cases ...***

Comment: Good post like always, but with your knowledge of the internals why isn't the cast from array->jsonb there. I can understand not implementing the other cast because the sql-array is more strongly typed. Is it just because PostgreSQL is averse to auto generating code to cast (int[], bigint[], text[]) etc.

Comment: @Evan: You'd use [**`to_jsonb()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) for array->jsonb conversion.

Comment: Does `SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(_js))` really guarantee that the ordering of the array is preserved? Isn't the optimizer allowed to theoretically alter the order of the rows coming out of json_array_elements_text?

Comment: @Felix: there is no formal guarantee in the SQL standard. (then again, set returning functions aren't even allowed in the SELECT list in standard SQL to begin with.) but there is an informal assertion in the Postgres manual. see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185862/3684 To be explicit - at the cost of a minor perfomance penalty - see:   https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27287/3684. Personally, I am 100 % sure this particular expression works as expected in every present and future version of Postgres since 9.4.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you so much for confirming this! I'm currently doing some research for an article that summarizes the formal and informal guarantees ordering guarantees provided by PostgreSQL and your answers have been incredibly helpful! If you'd be interested to review the article let me know, but no worries if not. I'm incredibly grateful for your StackOverflow contributions and learned a lot from you over the years!

Answer (score 26):

**PG 9.4+**

The accepted answer is definitely what you need, but for the sake of simplicity here is a helper I use for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(p_input jsonb)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$

SELECT array_agg(ary)::text[] FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(p_input) AS ary;

$function$;
```

Then just do:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_to_text_array('["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb);
```

**Updated 2/23/2020 in response to comments**: Comments are correct that this could be more efficient. At the time I posted there was no modularized solution offered so I offered one in earnest, if non-optimal. Since then Erwin has updated his answer with a simple and efficient function so I never updated mine. Updating it now since there is still attention coming to this answer

**One more update, because this just bit me**:
The above function will return `null` if there are no values. This may not be desirable depending on your situation. Here's a function which returns an empty array if the value is not `null`, but still returns null if the input is null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array_strict(p_input jsonb)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$

SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN p_input IS null 
    THEN null 
    ELSE coalesce(ary_out, ARRAY[]::text[]) 
  END
FROM (
  SELECT array_agg(ary)::text[] AS ary_out
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(p_input) AS ary
) AS extracted;

$function$
;
```

Comment: This function should be pure SQL so that the optimizer can peek into it. No need to use pgplsql here.

Comment: ... and it should be IMMUTABLE not VOLATILE, since it does not touch the database and any given input will always generate the same output.

Answer (score 10):

I've tested a few options. Here is my favorite query. Suppose we have a table containing id and json field. The json field contains array, which we want to turn into pg array.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   test 
WHERE  TRANSLATE(jsonb::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[] 
       && ARRAY[1,2,3];
```

It is working anywhere and faster than others, but looks crutchy)

Firstly json array is casted as text, and then we just change square brackets to parenthesis. Finally the text is being casted as array of required type.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('[1]'::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[];
```

and if you prefer text[] arrays

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('[1]'::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::TEXT[];
```

Comment: `SELECT TRANSLATE('{"name": "foo", "tags": ["foo", "bar"]}'::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[];
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"name": "foo", "tags": {"foo", "bar"}}"`
I think you have to add some explanation about how this is supposed to work.

Comment: The question is how to turn JSON array(!) into pg array. Suppose I have the table containing id and jsonb columns. JSONb column contains json array. Then

Comment: TRANSLATE(jsonb::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[] converts json array to pg array.

Comment: `SELECT translate('["foo", "bar"]'::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[];
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "foo"` It's not so bomb-proof...

Comment: Consider using text[] for these arrays

Comment: I like the approach but this will also replace `[` within the array string content as well unfortunately

Comment: This helped me out - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This question was asked on the [PostgreSQL mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOycyLQcR=Fr6QzLpe_AL10oVPxkpA-jA1jniZ7JuAsZsSf30w@mail.gmail.com) and I came up with this hackish way of converting JSON text to PostgreSQL text type via the JSON field extraction operator:

```
CREATE FUNCTION json_text(json) RETURNS text IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql
AS $$ SELECT ('['||$1||']')::json->>0 $$;

db=# select json_text(json_array_elements('["hello",1.3,"\u2603"]'));
 json_text 
-----------
 hello
 1.3
 ☃
```

Basically it converts the value into a single-element array and then asks for the first element.

Another approach would be to use this operator to extract all fields one-by-one. But for large arrays this is likely slower, as it needs to parse the whole JSON string for each array element, leading to O(n^2) complexity.

```
CREATE FUNCTION json_array_elements_text(json) RETURNS SETOF text IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql
AS $$ SELECT $1->>i FROM generate_series(0, json_array_length($1)-1) AS i $$;

db=# select json_array_elements_text('["hello",1.3,"\u2603"]');
 json_array_elements_text 
--------------------------
 hello
 1.3
 ☃
```

Answer (score 1):

These few functions, taken from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45243186/316857), are what I'm using and they're working great

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_array_casttext(json) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x) || ARRAY[]::text[] FROM json_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_casttext(jsonb) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x) || ARRAY[]::text[] FROM jsonb_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_array_castint(json) RETURNS int[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x)::int[] || ARRAY[]::int[] FROM json_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_castint(jsonb) RETURNS int[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x)::int[] || ARRAY[]::int[] FROM jsonb_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

In each of them, by concatenating with an empty array, they handle a case that had me racking my brain for a bit, in that if you try and cast an empty array from `json`/`jsonb` without it you'll get nothing returned, instead of an empty array (`{}`) as you would expect. I'm certain there's some optimization for them, but they're left as is for simplicity in explaining the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I like the translate solution mentioned so here's a tribute that doesn't interfere with the text content:

```
SELECT ('{' || RIGHT(LEFT( '[1]'::json::text ,-1),-1) || '}')::INTEGER[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js))';
```

is sweet and succinct, but has a caveat for me.
When invoked as:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_to_text_array(NULL);
```

It returns NULL, as desired for my use case.
However, when passed a null value of a JSON property, such as:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_to_text_array('{"my_value_is_null": null}'::JSONB -> 'my_value_is_null');
```

It throws an error stating "cannot extract elements from a scalar".

Maybe I'm missing a vital piece of understanding NULL value handling, but I've tracked the issue back inside the custom function, where the null valued property is passed in as a sting of value 'null'. So my modified version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$$SELECT CASE WHEN _js = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js)) END$$;
```

handles that by also returning NULL in that case, as if passed a regular, SQL NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) in Postgres 15.

**Creating a new composite type**

```
CREATE TYPE subitem AS (
   type integer,
   value real
);
```

**Creating a table that uses the composite type**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id serial not null unique primary key,
    subitems subitem[] -- An array of subitem
);
```

**Inserting data from a JSON array with objects:**

```
INSERT INTO items (subitems) VALUES (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT json_populate_recordset(
      null::subitem,
      '[{"type":1,"value":2},{"type":3,"value":4}]'
    )
  )
);
```

The first parameter to `json_populate_recordset` is used as the basis for how the records are to be created. It extracts the keys specified on the base, and the result after `ARRAY()` is an array of the correct type.

**To get the data back to JSON**

```
SELECT id, array_to_json(subitems) AS subitems
FROM items;
```