# json_array_elemnts() in FROM in postgresql 9.3 acting as where clause

Tags: postgresql, join, json, set-returning-functions

I am trying to extract array out of json in the FROM statement But issue occurs when certain json doesn't have that array in it and then query just ignores that row and doesn't get counted in the total count.

Instead the behaviour should be like if there's no array element in the particular json than it should still be counted in the total count value. Since I am using `json_array_elemnts()` in FROM clause and not WHERE clause.

Example:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM incidents_incident
   , json_array_elements(incidents_incident.incident_data -> 'field_52ca447762ba2')
WHERE resort_id = 1
AND dt_created >= '2015-06-01 00:00:00'
AND dt_created <= '2015-08-10 00:00:00';
```

Comment: What to count *exactly*? The number of elements in all JSON arrays `incident_data -> 'field_52ca447762ba2'` of qualifying rows in `incidents_incident`? That's what your query does now. Or the number of qualifying rows, plus the surplus if there are more than 1 elements in the array? That's what you get from [@Daniel's answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110800/3684). More explanation for `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83935/3684

Comment: Aside: Typically, you do ***not*** want to include the 00:00 of the next day in your selection, so you probably want: `AND dt_created <  '2015-08-10 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 1):

This query requests the **cartesian product** between `incidents_incident` and `json_array_elements(...)`.

When one of the elements of a product is empty, the result is empty.

This result doesn't depend on the WHERE clause or the fact that one the product comes from `json_array_elements()`. An empty table would have the same effect.

Presumably you want an unconstrained LEFT JOIN instead of the cartesian product:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM incidents_incident
LEFT JOIN json_array_elements(incidents_incident.incident_data -> 'field_52ca447762ba2')
  ON (true)
WHERE resort_id = 1
AND dt_created >= '2015-06-01 00:00:00'
AND dt_created <= '2015-08-10 00:00:00';
```