# Create dynamic WHERE clause from a JSON field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json

We have tables like this:

```
people_people (
   "id" integer...
   "attributes" HSTORE
)
object_permission (
    "permissions" JSON
)
```

An example of an `object_permission.permissions` is:

```
{"matricule":{"authorized_keys": ["12"],
              "unauthorized_keys": ["1", "2", "20"]},
 "departement":{"authorized_keys": ["it"],
                "unauthorized_keys": ["finance", "account"]},
 "access":{"authorized_keys": ["superuser", "user", "login"],
           "unauthorized_keys": ["web"]}}
```

From these data, I'd like to generate the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people_people
WHERE
(attributes->'matricule' IN ["12"]) AND
(attributes->'departement' IN ["it"]) AND
(attributes->'access' IN ["superuser", "user", "login"]);
```

How to generate dynamic `WHERE` clause based on a JSON field?
I don't want to use dynamic SQL because of the possible SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example to prove my point:

```
CREATE TABLE some_data (
    data hstore
);

INSERT INTO some_data
VALUES ('a=>bla'),
       ('access=>bla'),
       ('access=>user');
```

Now taking your JSON as an example, we can do something like this:

```
WITH condition_elements AS (
    SELECT key, 
           ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(value->'authorized_keys')) AS value 
      FROM jsonb_each('
        {
         "matricule":   {"authorized_keys":["12"],
                         "unauthorized_keys": ["1", "2", "20"]},
         "departement": {"authorized_keys": ["it"],
                         "unauthorized_keys":["finance", "account"]},
         "access":      {"authorized_keys" : ["superuser", "user", "login"],
                         "unauthorized_keys" :  ["web"]}
        }'::jsonb)
)
SELECT data->key AS key, 
       value, 
       data->key=ANY(value) AS matches
  FROM some_data, 
       condition_elements;
```

The actual output is to describe what to expect from above:

```
 key  │         value          │ matches 
──────┼────────────────────────┼─────────
      │ {superuser,user,login} │ 
 bla  │ {superuser,user,login} │ f
 user │ {superuser,user,login} │ t
      │ {12}                   │ 
      │ {12}                   │ 
      │ {12}                   │ 
      │ {it}                   │ 
      │ {it}                   │ 
      │ {it}                   │
```

If we move the necessary part to a condition, it will work nicely:

```
-- add some more data for testing
INSERT INTO some_data
VALUES ('departement=>bla,access=>bla'),
       ('departement=>it,access=>bla'),
       ('departement=>it,access=>login');

WITH condition_elements (... as above ...)
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT data, bool_and(data->key=ANY(value)) AS full_match
          FROM some_data, condition_elements
         GROUP BY data
       ) t
 WHERE full_match;

                  data                  │ full_match 
────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────
 "access"=>"login", "departement"=>"it" │ t
 "access"=>"user"                       │ t
```

Notes:

- It is always better to present real code in your question - like actual `CREATE TABLE` statements, a syntactically correct JSON snippet and a query that actually can run.
- For translating JSON arrays into PostgreSQL arrays, I used here a technique that is described in detail in Erwin Brandstetter's [excellent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/6219).
- Check the documentation about the different [JSON(B) operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).  It contains quite a lot of useful stuff.