# Customize jsonb key sort order involving arrays

Tags: postgresql, index, order-by, json, array

I have a table in PostgreSQL with some data:

```
create table t2 (
    key jsonb,
    value jsonb
);

INSERT INTO t2(key, value)
 VALUES
 ('1', '"test 1"')
,('2', '"test 2"')
,('3', '"test 3"')
,('[]', '"test 4"')
,('[1]', '"test 5"')
,('[2]', '"test 6"')
,('[3]', '"test 7"')
,('[1, 2]', '"test 8"')
,('[1, 2, 3]', '"test 9"')
,('[1, 3]', '"test 10"')
,('[1,2,4]', '"test 11"')
,('[1, 2,4]', '"test 12"')
,('[1,3,13]', '"test 13"')
,('[1, 2, 15]', '"test 15"');
```

And I try to sort these rows like that:

```
SELECT key FROM t2 order by key;
```

The result is:

```
[]
1
2
3
[1]
[2] <==
[3] <==
[1, 2]
[1, 3] <==
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 15]
[1, 3, 13]
```

But what I need is:

```
[]
1
2
3
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 15]
[1, 3] <==
[1, 3, 13]
[2] <==
[3] <==
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 8):

First off, your question as well as your column name `"key"` are misleading. The column key does not contain any JSON *keys*, only ***values***. Else we could use the function `jsonb_object_keys(jsonb)` to extract keys, but that's not so.

Assuming all your JSON arrays are either empty or hold integer numbers as demonstrated. And the scalar values (non-arrays) are also integer.

Your basic sort order would work with Postgres `integer` (or `numeric`) arrays. I use this little **helper function** to convert `jsonb` arrays to Postgres `int[]`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_arr2int_arr(_js jsonb)
   RETURNS int[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT j::int FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(_js) j)';
```

Explanation:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

Then add [`jsonb_typeof(jsonb)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to arrive at:

```
SELECT key
FROM   t2
ORDER  BY key <> '[]'             -- special case for empty array
        , jsonb_typeof(key) DESC  -- 'number' before 'array'
        , CASE jsonb_typeof(key)  -- sort arrays as converted int[]
            WHEN 'array'  THEN jsonb_arr2int_arr(key)
            WHEN 'number' THEN ARRAY[key::text::int]
          END;
```

Produces the desired result exactly.

#### Why?

[The manual for `jsonb` explains:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> The `btree` ordering for `jsonb` datums is seldom of great interest, but
>   for completeness it is:
>
> `Object > Array > Boolean > Number > String > Null`
>   `Object with n pairs > object with n - 1 pairs`
>    **`Array with n elements > array with n - 1 elements`**
>
> Objects with equal numbers of pairs are compared in the order:
>
> ```
> key-1, value-1, key-2 ...
> ```
>
> Note that object keys are compared in their storage order; in
>   particular, since shorter keys are stored before longer keys, this can
>   lead to results that might be unintuitive, such as:
>
> ```
> { "aa": 1, "c": 1} > {"b": 1, "d": 1}
> ```
>
> Similarly, arrays with equal numbers of elements are compared in the
>   order:
>
> ```
> element-1, element-2 ...
> ```

Bold emphasis mine.
That's why `jsonb '[2]' < jsonb '[1, 2]'`.
But Postgres arrays just sort element-by-element: `'{2}'::int[] > '{1, 2}'` - exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the problem to order your results by json integer values.
Try:

```
select myjson from mytable order by (myjson->>'some_int')::int;
```

In your case it seems to be an array for the ordering key. So first try to concat the values in your "key" field.