# Postgres Ordering by a Json Array

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.6

I have the following json that I am storing in a jsonb field. For every record representing a product, it contains various categories and in each category a is priority level.

```
[
      {
        "priority": 0,
        "description": "",
        "categoryName": "Cars",
        "title": ""
      },
      {
        "priority": 1,
        "description": "",
        "categoryName": "Trucks",
        "title": ""
      },
      {
        "priority": 2,
        "description": "",
        "categoryName": "Vans",
        "title": ""
      }
    ]
```

I would like to order the data by various categories dynamically using the *priority* field such that, if I am displaying all the products in the category Cars, I will order by the 0 array element, if I am displaying all the products in the category Vans, I order by the 2 array element.

Currently, to order by the first array element I am able to do so:

```
ORDER BY OBJECT_DATA->'productCategories'->0->>'priority'
```

However, I would like to order by first selecting the the array value (`categoryName`) and then using the array value to select its priority.

As an example: order by Trucks->priority (1)

I am using PostgresSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming from your code snippet that the displayed JSON is the value of a key `"productCategories"` in a `jsonb` column `object_data` of your table `tbl`, you can achieve your desired sort order like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT elem->>'priority' AS prio
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.object_data->'productCategories') a(elem)
   WHERE  elem->>'categoryName' = 'Trucks'  -- your category here
   ) a ON true                              -- preserve all rows from t
ORDER  BY prio;                             -- NULL values are sorted last
```

Related answers with detailed explanation:

- [How to sort objects in an array inside a json or jsonb value by a property of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206719/in-pl-pgsql-how-do-i-sort-a-json-or-jsonb-array-of-objects-by-a-property-of-the/49241241#49241241)
- [Customize jsonb key sort order involving arrays](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142067/customize-jsonb-key-sort-order-involving-arrays)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)