# Clever way to order a json item by key in postgresql (two examples)

Tags: postgresql, json, order-by, sorting

I need to sort a json item in a record, so here are two examples:

## First case

```
create table jsontable (
    jsonitem json
);
```

Next I insert a json item:

```
insert into jsontable(jsonitem) values ('{ "3" : "foo", "2" : "bar", "1" : "qux" }');
```

Then I query the values:

```
select t.jsonitem from jsontable t;
                 jsonitem                  
-------------------------------------------
 { "3" : "foo", "2" : "bar", "1" : "qux" }
(1 row)
```

Let's suppose the key is unique and is an integer > 0;

**Question 1:** ¿ How to sort the json item values by the key value, and get the following ?

```
{ "1" : "qux", "2" : "bar", "3" : "foo" }
```

## Second case

This case use named keys and named values.

```
create table jsontable_arr(
   jsonitem json
   );
```

```
insert into jsontable_arr(jsonitem) values ('[  { "key" : "3" , "value": "foo"}, { "key" : "2" , "value": "bar"}, { "key" : "1" , "value": "qux"} ]');
```

```
select t.* from jsontable_arr t;
                                                jsonitem
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [  { "key" : "3" , "value": "foo"}, { "key" : "2" , "value": "bar"}, { "key" : "1" , "value": "qux"} ]
(1 row)
```

**Question 2:** ¿ How to sort the json array item by the key value, and get the following?

```
[  { "key" : "1" , "value": "qux"}, { "key" : "2" , "value": "bar"}, {"key" : "3" , "value": "foo"} ]
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want your database to do unnatural things? Supposedly you need this sort order for display, so why not make the application layer do the ordering.

Comment: Good, that's one possible answer, let the application to that and not the database.

Comment: @mustaccio: And why not let the RDBMS do it, which is typically much better at sorting?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the `json` datatype and not `jsonb` which is better for virtually all use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that order of **array items** is a different issue than **order of keys** in JSON object. See:

- [How to sort objects in an array inside a json or jsonb value by a property of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241241/939860)

For your **first example** (implying integer sort), simply casting to `jsonb` would do the job. It happens to sort keys the way you want by default:

```
SELECT jsonitem::jsonb FROM jsontable;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=47efe7d9c1e8070b665207a97b281025)*

Or use `jsonb` instead of `json` to begin with.

**However**, it's not strictly integer sort. Keys are strings. Shorter keys sort before longer keys, which works as desired with only digits. But not necessarily with anything else. Like negative numbers:

```
2, 3, -1
```

Then again, [your solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/282180/3684) does string sort according to the default collation, i.e. breaks integer sort for numbers not comprised of the same number of digits:

```
111, 22, 3
```

You didn't specify exactly. This would do integer sort properly:

```
select id, json_object_agg(key, value) AS jsonitem
from  (
   select id, key, value
   from   tbl
   ORDER  BY id, key::int  -- !!!
   ) tbl
group  by id;
```

Of course, the cast to integer raises an exception for any string that's not a legal integer representation.

Sorting in a subquery *once* as this is typically much faster than the per-item sort you get from an added `ORDER BY` in an aggregate function. This works, because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work.

See:

- [Is it REALLY possible that the order will not be guaranteed for this particular redundant derived table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184149/is-it-really-possible-that-the-order-will-not-be-guaranteed-for-this-particular/185862#185862)
- [Customize jsonb key sort order involving arrays](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142067/customize-jsonb-key-sort-order-involving-arrays)

Your **second example** is a different beast, trying to sort an array with JSON objects by the (single!?) nested key. You could reorder arrays like this:

```
SELECT j.id, arr.js_sorted
FROM   jsonarr j
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(value) AS js_sorted
   FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM   json_array_elements(j.jsonitem)
      ORDER  BY (value->>'key')::int  -- true integer sort!
      ) sub
   ) arr;
```

It really depends on where your values come from, what they can be *exactly*, and how you want to sort *exactly*.

Answer (score 1):

The example above was the result of a json_object_agg function, according to the manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

> The aggregate functions array_agg, json_agg, jsonb_agg,
> json_object_agg, jsonb_object_agg, string_agg, and xmlagg, as well as
> similar user-defined aggregate functions, **produce meaningfully
> different result values depending on the order of the input values**.

However you can specify the order inside aggregates:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

> aggregate_name (expression [ , ... ] [ order_by_clause ] ) [ FILTER (
> WHERE filter_clause ) ]

So, I finally found the solution while assembling the json object and is to specify the order inside the json_object_agg() function using an 'order by' like this:

```
select 
  json_object_agg(
      key, value order by key
  )  AS jsonitem,
from table key_value_tbl;
```