# Unquoting JSON strings; print JSON strings without quotes

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-10, string-representation

```
SELECT json_array_elements('["one", "two"]'::json)
```

gives result

```
| json_array_elements |
| :------------------ |
| "one"               |
| "two"               |
```

I would like to have the same but without the quotes:

```
one
two
```

Looks like I can't use [`->>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40928412/1024794) here because I don't have field names in the JSON. It's just an array of strings.

Postgres version:
PostgreSQL 10.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00), 64-bit

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: This question have an answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57121/110455

Comment: @McNets - what about [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LvcKQvaDCSJWFkL5ndBx9/1)?

Comment: @Vérace on db-fiddle shows results without quotes but dbfiddle.uk shows results with quotes. I can't check it on my postgres VM (I don't remember the password) but I suppose it will show the quotes.

Comment: @Vérace psql shows it with quotes too

Comment: There are lies, damned lies and fiddles! `(*)` :-) They all appear to have bugs of one sort or another, and don't even get me started on tablets! <blood pressure rising already>...  `(*)` [famous expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics). Thanks for pointing out my error though!

Comment: @McNets link has the answer, one just needs to use _jsonb_array_elements_text_

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default `json->text` coercion outputs with a double quote (`"`) because coercing from `text` to a `json` string requires you to double-quote your input. To get rid of the double-quotes, use `TRIM`

```
SELECT x, trim('"' FROM x::text)
FROM json_array_elements('["one", "two"]'::json) AS t(x);
   x   | btrim 
-------+-------
 "one" | one
 "two" | two
(2 rows)
```

Important point though, you lose some utility if you do that. All JSONB types get returned in a textual form that can be used to go back to `jsonb` with the `text->jsonb` coercion. It's a bijective mapping function. Losing that means `null` and `"null"` are the same, as are `1` and `"1"`.

```
SELECT x, trim('"' FROM x::text)
FROM json_array_elements('[null, "null", 1, "1"]') AS t(x);
   x    | btrim 
--------+-------
 null   | null
 "null" | null
 1      | 1
 "1"    | 1
(4 rows)
```

### Internals..

If you want to know what's happening. All types can provide an `_out` which takes them to `text` or `_send` which takes them to binary representation and a reciprocal `_in` and `_recv` which takes them from those forms and maps back to the types. Here you're getting `jsonb_out`,

1. [`jsonb_out`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L132) which [calls `JsonbToCstring`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L137)
2. [`JsonbToCstring`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L431) which [calls `JsonbToCStringWorker`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L433)
3. [`JsonbToCStringWorker`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L449) which [calls `jsonb_put_escaped_value`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L543)
4. [`jsonb_put_escaped_value(StringInfo out, JsonbValue *scalarVal)`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L312) which [calls `escape_json`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/cb5d94295986298af666534970f9bb3715574646/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L320)
5. [`escape_json(StringInfo buf, const char *str)`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/524d64ea8e3e49b4fda41ff9b2f048b697384058/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c#L2461) which [adds the `"`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/524d64ea8e3e49b4fda41ff9b2f048b697384058/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c#L2465) and it's hardcoded. **No other way.**

Comment: Note that btrim gives incorrect result if the string contains double quotes while @slava-v's answer below is better: `SELECT x, trim('"' FROM x::text), x#>>'{}' FROM json_array_elements('[null, "nu\"ll", 1, "1"]') AS t(x);`

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT value#>>'{}' as col FROM json_array_elements('["one", "two"]'::json);
```

Result:

```
col
---
one
two
```

Comment: As a bit of an explanation: The operators that contain `>>` seem to generally convert a JSON to unescaped text: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html. This answer is probably preferable since the escaping is probably not limited to adding quotation marks, but also escapes quotation marks in the text and some special characters. The samples above just so happen not to contain any. (“Probably” because I didn’t test it.)

Comment: Rather the `#>>` is a JSON operator to return an object at a path, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

Comment: "How do you unquote a JSON string in postgres?" "Oh it's easy, just add `#>>'{}'` after.  Should be obvious."  Take your upvote, wizard!

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT json_array_elements_text('["one", "two"]'::json)
```

of if using jsonb instead:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text('["one", "two"]'::jsonb)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `jsonb_array_elements` instead:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements('["one", "two"]'::jsonb) ->> 0
```

Result:

```
col
---
one
two
```