# Extract JSON array of numbers from JSON array of objects

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have a table containing a json array of objects similar to this:

```
id    |   record
____________________
name1 | [{"a":0, "b":x}, {"a":1, "b":y}, {"a":2, "b":z}, ...]
```

I would like to get a table containing a json array of only, say, the "a" values:

```
id    |   record
____________________
name1 | [0, 1, 2, ...]
```

I use PostgreSQL 11, so the latest functions are acceptable.

Comment: [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to first unnest the array elements, and then aggregate back each value:

```
select id, 
       (select jsonb_agg(t -> 'a') from jsonb_array_elements(record) as x(t)) as record
from the_table;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ZONHTW97204