# How to loop through JSON array of JSON objects to see if it contains a value that I am looking for in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-9.6

Here is an example of the json object

```
rawJSON = [
   {"a":0, "b":7},
   {"a":1, "b":8}, 
   {"a":2, "b":9}
]
```

And I have a table that essentially looks like this.

```
demo Table

id | ...(other columns)      | rawJSON
------------------------------------
0  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":7},{"a":1, "b":8}, {"a":2, "b":9}]
1  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":17},{"a":11, "b":5}, {"a":12, "b":5}]
```

What I want is to return a row which insideRawJSON has value from "a" of less than 2 AND the value from "b" of less than 8. THEY MUST BE FROM THE SAME JSON OBJECT.

Essentially the query would similarly look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE FOR ANY JSON OBJECT in rawJSON column -> "a" < 2 AND -> "b" < 8
```

And therefore it will return

```
id | ...(other columns)      | rawJSON
------------------------------------
0  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":7},{"a":1, "b":8}, {"a":2, "b":9}]
```

I have searched from several posts here but was not able to figure it out. 
[Extract JSON array of numbers from JSON array of objects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229069/extract-json-array-of-numbers-from-json-array-of-objects)
[How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)

I was thinking of creating a plgpsql function but wasn't able to figure out .

Any advice I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!!

I would also like to avoid CROSS JOIN LATERAL because it will slow down the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way around unnesting the array for every row (the drawbacks of de-normalizing data). But you don't need a cross join, an `EXISTS` condition should work just fine.

```
select *
from demo d
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(d.rawjson) as r(jdoc)
              where (jdoc ->> 'a')::int < 2
                and (jdoc ->> 'b')::int < 8);
```

If your columns is not a `jsonb` (which it should be), use `json_each()` instead

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=974f30a33b3b100b609f7cab64a0020a)

Comment: I am sorry, I tried running this, but I get this error
```

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 8:               where (jdoc ->> 'a')::int < 2
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

here is the db fiddle [link]  (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=600397ab673f712908fadb489f8d9320)

Comment: Then `rawjson` is a `text` not a `jsonb` (or at least `json`) column. You will have to cast it then: `rawjson::jsonb`. You should change the column's data type to `jsonb`

Comment: I can confirm that this is not working

Comment: @Madeo: you are right, that should be `jsonb_array_elements()` not `jsonb_each()`. I corrected the answer

Comment: Yes, not is working, thanks