# How to convert strings extracted from JSON to a numeric type for aggregates?

Tags: postgresql, json

I am struggling to extract data from this JSON object in PostgreSQL:

```
"temperature": {
"boiler_temp": {
  "values": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "3",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "4",
    "7",
    "7",
    "7",
    "7",
    "4",
    null,
    "4",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "6",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "5",
    "2",
    "2"
  ]
}
}
```

I am using `jsonb_array_elements()` to extract it but they are returned as a string like '1', '2' and so on and so forth. My goal is to try and find the "avg": 5,"max": 7,"min": 1 for this data set however because I am returning them as string I am getting a value of null and an error:

My current code:

```
(select MIN(x::text::int) from jsonb_array_elements((data#>>'{temperature,boiler_temp}')::jsonb->'values') AS x) as mininum_temp
```

And I am getting an error:

> ```
> ERROR: Invalid Syntax for integer :""1""
> ```

Comment: Aside: Your JSON should store number or integer primitives not strings. `jsonb_array_elements_text()` returns `text` either way, but then we could be sure to get valid numeric literals that can be cast to `numeric` (or `integer`) safely - else an exception is raised. About `jsonb_array_elements_text()`: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684

Comment: exactly my thoughts, but the system was built like that and I am creating a report for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract them as text using `jsonb_array_elements_text()`, then you can cast it to an integer:

```
select min(x.val::int), max(x.val::int), avg(x.val::int)
from the_table
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(data #> '{temperature,boiler_temp,values}') as x(val)
```