# PostgreSQL Convert JSONB array to string

Tags: postgresql, json-path

I am trying to flatten a nested JSONB object into a string so that I can run regex on it.

To retrieve the relevant text fields, I'm using

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(posts.content, 'strict $.**.text') FROM posts
```

which returns a jsonb (array). I've tried naively casting the jsonb to `::text[]` and then `array_to_string`, but that results in the following type error:

```
cannot cast type jsonb to text[]. null
```

I have also tried wrapping the result in a `jsonb_array_elements_text`, but that gives me a list of rows for *all posts* instead of just one.

Edit: Following this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/238642), I've come up with

```
SELECT posts.post_id, plaintext.plaintext
FROM posts, LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(value::text, ', ') AS plaintext
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(posts.content, 'strict $.**.text'))
   ) plaintext;
```

Comment: You might *answer* your own question instead of editing an answer into the question. Or do you want to close it? Or you provide the actual regex pattern you want to run. Chances are, there are faster solutions. This transformation is rather costly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Do you know of a faster way to do this? I'll try to add more info in the post.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit counterintuitive.
This worked for me in postgres 13:

Get an array:

```
ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text( 
        jsonb_path_query_array(table.jsonb_column, '$.item.*.subitem')
))
```

Get an array into a string:

```
array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text( 
        jsonb_path_query_array(table.jsonb_column, '$.item.*.subitem')
)), ' ')
```