# Convert an optional JSONB field to a text array?

Tags: postgresql, cast, jsonb

In `my_table`, the `misc` column is `jsonb` with default value `{}`. Some rows have `misc.names` as an array of text values; other rows do not have the `misc.names` key.

I want to copy that data to a separate `names::text[]` column, with a command like:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET names = COALESCE(misc->>'names', ARRAY[]::text[])
```

In other words, "if the row has a list of text values in `misc->>'names'`, put those in the `names` column, but if `misc->>'names'` is `NULL` in that row, put an empty text array in the `names` column."

However, this fails with:

`ERROR:  42804: COALESCE types text and text[] cannot be matched`

I don't understand what the error is saying. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `misc->'names'` *"a list of text values"* or an actual JSON array? What do you get for `jsonb_typeof (misc->'names')`? Also (as always) your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `misc->'names'` is an actual JSON array (not "a list of text values"), I suggest this custom translation function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_to_text_array(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js))';
```

Detailed explanation:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

Then your `UPDATE` query can be:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    names = COALESCE(jsonb_array_to_text_array(misc->'names'), '{}')
WHERE  names <> COALESCE(jsonb_array_to_text_array(misc->'names'), '{}');
```

Note the added (optional) `WHERE` clause to skip empty updates that would not change anything (at full cost). This is assuming `names` is defined `NOT NULL`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

Answer (score 1):

`misc->>'names'`, while kind of appearing as an array, is actually `text`, not `text[]`.  You would need to convert the jsonb array into a postgresql text array.  The datatypes and a way to perform the conversion are explored in this [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9Pf5dWuffzR5o3Xh6GR2U/1), showing how a simple `string_to_array` conversion is probably what not what is desired, versus building an array from the results of a call to `jsonb_array_elements_text`.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id          SERIAL,
    misc        jsonb DEFAULT '{}',
    expected    text[],
    names       text[]
);

INSERT  INTO my_table ( misc, expected )
VALUES  ( '{ "names": [ "A", "B", "C" ] }', ARRAY[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ] ),
        ( DEFAULT, ARRAY[]::text[] );
        
SELECT  misc, expected, names,
        misc->>'names',
        pg_typeof( misc->>'names' ),
        string_to_array( misc->>'names', ',' ),
        pg_typeof( string_to_array( misc->>'names', ',' ) ),
        ARRAY( SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text( misc->'names' ) ),
        pg_typeof( ARRAY( SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text( misc->'names' ) ) )
FROM    my_table;

UPDATE  my_table
    SET names = COALESCE( ARRAY( SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text( misc->'names' ) ), ARRAY[]::text[] );
    
SELECT  misc, expected, names
FROM    my_table;
```