# Order of returned rows with IN statement

Tags: postgresql, order-by

I know that the order of returned rows is not guaranteed with the `IN` statement in Postgres. For example if I do this:

```
SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (13589, 16674, 13588)
```

I may get this result:

```
16674
13588
13589
```

However, I want returned rows to respect the order in the `IN` list, so I found few solutions online, such as:

```
SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (13589, 16674, 13588)
ORDER BY POSITION(id::text in '(13589, 16674, 13588)')
```

or

```
SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id IN (13589, 16674, 13588)
ORDER BY id = 13589 desc,
         id = 16674 desc,
         id = 13588 desc;
```

I wonder if there is a nicer way to do this, or better yet more efficient?

Comment: "Nicer" is quite subjective; would you consider using `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` as nicer ? As to efficiency, I'm pretty sure optimizer will generate the same plan.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `WITH ORDINALITY` in Postgres 9.4+

Introduced with Postgres 9.4. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

> When a function in the `FROM` clause is suffixed by `WITH ORDINALITY,` a
> `bigint` column is appended to the output which starts from 1 and
> increments by 1 for each row of the function's output. This is most
> useful in the case of set returning functions such as `unnest()`.

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM   unnest('{13589, 16674, 13588}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(id, order_nr)
JOIN   users u USING (id)
ORDER  BY x.order_nr;
```

#### array or set?

`x IN (set)` statements are rewritten internally in Postgres to `x = ANY (array)`, which is equivalent:

```
SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.id = ANY ('{13589, 16674, 13588}')
```

You can see for yourself with `EXPLAIN`.

### Postgres 9.3 or earlier

For now, to preserve the order of elements, you could:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM  (
   SELECT arr, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS order_nr
   FROM  (SELECT '{13589, 16674, 13588}'::int[]) t(arr)
   ) x
JOIN   users u ON u.id = x.arr[x.order_nr]
ORDER  BY x.order_nr;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac6875e9808065190cb2c53560a44f20)*

Further reading:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rewrite the condition slightly you could do something like this:

```
with id_list (id, sort_order) as (
   values 
      (13589, 1), 
      (16674, 2),
      (13588, 3)
)
select u.id
from users u
  join id_list il on il.id = u.id
order by il.sort_order;
```

You can also put the `values` clause directly into the join:

```
select u.id
from users u
  join (
   values 
      (13589, 1), 
      (16674, 2),
      (13588, 3)
  ) as il(id, sort_order) on il.id = u.id
order by il.sort_order;
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter's method has the nice advantage that it can use an array of integers as a bind variable from a host language.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: yes, absolutely. I just wanted to show a different way of doing this.