# Join external data in SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, temporary-tables, postgresql-performance

I have few (~20) names of products corresponding to an integer id that needs to be joined on products while exporting products data (using `COPY (<query>) TO`). The burden is that these names do not rest in DB, rather in Redis (rails's translations fyi). Therefore, I'll be collecting these names before each export. Now, having these names outside the DB, how can I build the query to join them?

I've tried to join these names on-the-fly:

```
SELECT
...
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]) AS id,
           unnest($${"name1", "name2", "name3"}$$::text[]) AS name
) AS product_names ON product_names.id = products.type_id
...
```

But I've got busted by the amount of products rows (~500k) and lacking indices for that structure. Is there some (better) way to join these data on-fly? I guess one cannot index these on-fly data though.

Which is a good way to solve that situation? I can think of creating temporary table like:

```
SELECT ... INTO TEMPORARY ...;
```

but is it wise to have that stay on for long transaction, while exporting (~30 mins)? Or can I omit transactions while using temporary tables and how? Or am I just troubling myself with needless problems while the best solution is to just store those names as a regular table, only truncating it before each export to have actual names?

-- postgres 9.3.10

Comment: You cannot pass transactions at all (except some specialized cases like `DROP DATABASE`).  On the other hand, it sounds like the data you try to join to do not change very rapidly.  If this is the case, you can import them into a table - it should not necessarily be a temporary one, you can create a physical table just as well.  In both cases, you can build indexes on this table, if it helps.  The `unnest()` solution won't be very efficient for large arrays - however, you may try it in smaller chunks.  I'd expect the import+index build+export solution much faster anyway.

Comment: Please, always provide your version of Postgres, especially when trying to optimize performance. And `I've got busted` is not a very helpful description of the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming current Postgres **9.4**.

Since you are dealing with just ~ 20 names of products, it's largely irrelevant how you provide those to the query. An index would be a waste of time, Postgres is going to use a sequential scan anyway (judging from what you disclosed in the question).

You can use a temporary table, which lives for the duration of the session, not just transaction like you seem to assume. And you can even create indexes on temp tables, it just wouldn't help in this case.
Be sure to run `ANALYZE` on temp tables manually:

- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694)

Or you can unnest a provided array literal just as well. But don't rely on the outdated trick of unnesting two arrays in the `SELECT` list in parallel. This is error prone. Move it to the from clause. I'd suggest:

```
SELECT
...
LEFT JOIN unnest('{name1,name2,name3}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY
  product_names (name, type_id) USING (type_id)
...
```

More:

- [Order of returned record with IN statement postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59394/order-of-returned-record-with-in-statement-postgres/59401#59401)

Assuming the column name `type_id` is unambiguous in the tables to the left.

If you don't actually have ascending `type_id` starting with 1 like your example suggests, consider the new variant of `unnest()` taking multiple array parameters:

```
SELECT
...
LEFT JOIN unnest('{4,7,9}'::int[], '{name1,name2,name3}'::text[])
  product_names (type_id, name) USING (type_id)
...
```

More:

- [Passing arrays to stored procedures in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860)

Comment: Thanks for that much info! I've needed to clear up some of my thoughts. As for my problem: it turned out I've been badly collecting that product types, which resulted in huge number of them. Anyway, since I need to make it work with postgres 9.3.+, could you say more, why is it bad to unnest two arrays in parallel?

Comment: @OndřejŽelazko: Not necessarily bad, just non-standard and prone to errors. This related answer provides a detailed assessment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860