# Replacing substrings in array elements

Tags: postgresql, update, array

I have a table with an array of URLs in column `urls`. Now there's a need to update some URLs changing the hostname. E.g.:

```
{https://storage.host1.com/file.jpg, https://storage.host1.com/file2.jpg}
```

should become:

```
{https://data.newhost.net/file.jpg, https://data.newhost.net/file2.jpg}
```

Got stuck on array elements string replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only replace the leading hostname - and only update rows where anything changes to begin with:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    urls = t1.urls
FROM  (
   SELECT t.id, u.*
   FROM   tbl t
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE u.url ^@ 'https://storage.host1.com/') AS hit
           , array_agg(regexp_replace(url, '^https://storage.host1.com/', 'https://data.newhost.net/')) AS urls
      FROM   unnest(t.urls) u(url)
      ) u ON true
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id = t1.id
AND    t1.hit;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iW5LQrtN)

Since elements are re-aggregated right after being unnested, original order should be preserved. But see:

- [Order of returned rows with IN statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59394/order-of-returned-rows-with-in-statement/59401#59401)

Pretty expensive, as all arrays are unnested, each element is checked, and then all arrays are re-aggregated. There are no clean & easy index options to identify qualifying rows cheaply, and only process those. (You might use a workaround like a trigram index on the text representation of the array ...)

If you have to do this often, consider normalizing your DB design, with a 1:n relationship to a separate `urls` table. Would make this operation **much** simpler and faster.