# Unnest multiple arrays into rows

Tags: postgresql, array, bulk-insert, set-returning-functions

I have been [shown a great way to bulkinsert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23072354/1382306) with this example:

```
WITH p AS (
    INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) 
    SELECT $1 
    RETURNING id) 
INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a) 
SELECT p.id, a 
FROM   p, unnest($2::text[]) AS a
```

However, I need to insert multiple rows from multiple arrays, so I tried this syntax:

```
WITH p AS (
    INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) 
    SELECT $1 
    RETURNING id) 
INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a, column_b) 
SELECT p.id, a, b 
FROM   p, unnest($2::text[]) AS a, unnest($3::bigint[]) AS b
```

I have a primary key on `parent_table_id` and `column_a`, and when I try to execute this query, Postgres complains of a duplicate key violation.

How should the arrays be unwrapped so that they form individual rows?

In other words, if `$2` and `$3` both have two entries, how can the first entry of `$2` only be inserted with the first entry of `$3` and the same for the respective second entries?

If this is not possible, can I construct a multidimensional array?  If so, how should it be passed with multiple array types, and what is the multidimensional array syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This would do what you desire:

```
WITH p AS (
    INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) 
    SELECT $1 
    RETURNING id) 
INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a, column_b) 
SELECT p.id, t.a, t.b 
FROM   p, (SELECT unnest($2::text[]) AS a, unnest($3::bigint[]) AS b) t
```

The subtle difference here is that [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) calls in the same `SELECT` list are unnested *in parallel* if the number of elements is *identical*. Careful though: In Postgres 9.6 or older, if the number is *not* the same, it results in a Cartesian product instead. The behavior was sanitized in **Postgres 10**. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414884/939860)

You could use a cleaner form with `generate_subscripts()` or other techniques, but those would be much more verbose. Details in this related question:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

#### Postgres 9.4

The new `WITH ORDINALITY` in Postgres 9.4 allows a much cleaner (and only moderately more verbose) form for this:

```
WITH p AS (...)
INSERT INTO child_table (...)
SELECT p.id, ta.a, tb.b 
FROM   p
     , unnest($2::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS ta(a, rn)
JOIN   unnest($3::bigint[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS tb(b, rn) USING (rn);
```

And this special case can be **even simpler** with the new form of `unnest()` that accepts multiple arrays:

```
WITH p AS (...)
INSERT INTO child_table (...)
SELECT p.id, t.a, t.b 
FROM   p, unnest($2::text[], $3::bigint[]) AS t(a, b);
```

Example in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494907/939860).

Answer (score -1):

I solved with:

```
INSERT INTO foo(Val,i,j)
SELECT myArr[i][j] ,i,j 
FROM Generate_Series(1,lbound) i 
JOIN Generate_Series(1,ubound) j
    ON true
```