# How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, update, array, json

I'm facing an issue regarding using the JSON data type in PostgreSQL. I try to achieve storing a Java model denormalized in the DB. The model features lists of complex objects. Thus, I decided to model those as JSON in native PostgreSQL arrays.

This is a stripped down snippet of my table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test.persons
(
  id UUID,
  firstName TEXT,
  lastName TEXT,
  communicationData JSON[],
  CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

As you can see it is a person featuring a list of communication data objects in JSON. One of such objects might look like this:

```
{"value" : "03334/254147", "typeId" : "ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-6a5f6e63dbf6"}
```

I can easily append such a JSON object to an array using PostgreSQL's array_append. However, I fail at removing a known value from the array. Consider f.e. this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE test.persons
SET communicationData = array_remove(
      communicationData, 
      '{"value" : "03334/254147", "typeId" : "ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-6a5f6e63dbf6"}'::JSON
    )
WHERE id = 'f671eb6a-d603-11e3-bf6f-07ba007d953d';
```

This fails with `ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`. Do you have a hint how I could remove a known value from the JSON array? It would also be possible to remove by position in the array, as I know that one also...

PostgreSQL version is 9.3.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `jsonb` in Postgres 9.4 or later

Consider the [**`jsonb`** data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) in Postgres 9.4 or later. The 'b' at the end stands for 'binary'. Among other things, there is an [equality operator (`=`) for `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Most people will want to switch.

[Depesz blog about jsonb.](https://www.depesz.com/2014/03/25/waiting-for-9-4-introduce-jsonb-a-structured-format-for-storing-json/)

### `json`

There is no `=` operator defined for the data type [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html), because there is no well defined method to establish equality for whole `json` values. But see below.

You *could* cast to `text` and then use the `=` operator. This is short (and typically slow as it can't use a plain index), but only works if your text representation happens to match. Inherently unreliable, except for corner cases. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296054/939860)

Or you can [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) the array and use the [**`->>`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to get the JSON object field as `text` and compare individual fields.

#### Test table

Two rows, first like in the question, second with simple values.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  tbl_id int PRIMARY KEY
, jar    json[]
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
  (1, '{"{\"value\" : \"03334/254146\", \"typeId\" : \"ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-f5\"}"
       ,"{\"value\" : \"03334/254147\", \"typeId\" : \"ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-f6\"}"
       ,"{\"value\" : \"03334/254148\", \"typeId\" : \"ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-f7\"}"}')

, (2, '{"{\"value\" : \"a\", \"typeId\" : \"x\"}"
       ,"{\"value\" : \"b\", \"typeId\" : \"y\"}"
       ,"{\"value\" : \"c\", \"typeId\" : \"z\"}"}');
```

#### Demos

##### Demo 1

You *could* use `array_remove()` with `text` representations (unreliable).

```
SELECT tbl_id
     , jar, array_length(jar, 1) AS jar_len
     , jar::text[] AS t, array_length(jar::text[], 1) AS t_len
     , array_remove(jar::text[], '{"value" : "03334/254147", "typeId" : "ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-f6"}'::text) AS t_result
     , array_remove(jar::text[], '{"value" : "03334/254147", "typeId" : "ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-f6"}'::text)::json[] AS j_result
FROM   tbl;
```

##### Demo 2

Unnest the array and test fields of individual elements.

```
SELECT tbl_id, array_agg(j) AS j_new
FROM   tbl, unnest(jar) AS j   -- LATERAL JOIN
WHERE  j->>'value' <> '03334/254146'
AND    j->>'typeId' <> 'ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-6a5f6e63dbf5'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

##### Demo 3

Alternative test with row type.

```
SELECT tbl_id, array_agg(j) AS j_new
FROM   tbl, unnest(jar) AS j   -- LATERAL JOIN
WHERE  (j->>'value', j->>'typeId') NOT IN (
          ('03334/254146', 'ea4e7d7e-7b87-4628-ba50-6a5f6e63dbf5')
        , ('a', 'x')
       )
GROUP  BY 1;
```

### `UPDATE`

This is how you could implement your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    jar = j.jar
FROM   tbl t1
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT j
      FROM   unnest(t1.jar) AS j  -- LATERAL JOIN
      WHERE  j->>'value'  <> 'a'
      AND    j->>'typeId' <> 'x'
      ) AS jar
   ) j
WHERE  t1.tbl_id = 2              -- only relevant rows
AND    t1.tbl_id = t.tbl_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zA9A3H7U)

About the implicit `LATERAL JOIN`:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)
- [Query for element of array in JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19868697/939860)

About unnesting arrays:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

#### DB design

To simplify your situation consider an **normalized schema**: a separate table for the JSON values (instead of the array column), in a n:1 relationship to the main table.

Comment: It works like a charm. Yes, it would be easier with normalized data, but I'm in a 98% read, 2% write scenario. So I wanted to experiment with denormalization :-)

Is there anything releated planned for Postgres 9.4 which might help with the original question?

Comment: @spa: Actually, Postgres 9.4 will bring `jsonb`. I expect you'll love it. Added a chapter with links.

Comment: That's really cool. Thanks for the heads up.