# How to unnest and GROUP BY elements of a JSON array?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, json, array

Given the `band` table, with a `json` column holding an array :

```
id | people
---+-------------
1  | ['John', 'Thomas']
2  | ['John', 'James']
3  | ['James', 'George']
```

How to list the number of bands each name is part of?
**Desired output:**

```
name   | count
-------+------------
John   | 2
James  | 2
Thomas | 1
George | 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data type of the column `people` is `json`, as is the result of `json_array_elements(people)`. And there is no equality operator (`=`) for the data type `json`. So you also cannot run `GROUP BY` on it. More:

- [How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64759/how-to-remove-known-elements-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql/64765#64765)

`jsonb` has an equality operator, so [the "workaround" in your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208521/3684) is to cast to `jsonb` and use the equivalent `jsonb_array_elements()`. The cast adds cost:

```
jsonb_array_elements(people::jsonb)
```

Since Postgres 9.4 we also have [**`json_array_elements_text(json)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) returning array elements as `text`. Related:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

So:

```
SELECT p.name, count(*) AS c
FROM   band b, json_array_elements_text(b.people) p(name)
GROUP  BY p.name;
```

It seems more convenient to get names as `text` instead of `jsonb` objects (double-quoted in text representation) and your "desired output" indicates you want / need `text` in the result to begin with.

`GROUP BY` on `text` data is also cheaper than on `jsonb`, so this alternative "workaround" should be faster for two reasons. (Test with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)`.)

For the record, there was nothing wrong with [your original answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/208521/revisions). The comma (`,`) is just as "correct" as `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. Having been defined earlier in standard SQL does no make it inferior. See:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

Neither is it more portable to other RDBMS, and since `jsonb_array_elements()` or `json_array_elements_text()` aren't portable to other RDBMS to begin with, that's also irrelevant. The short query does not get any clearer with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` IMO, but the last bit is just my personal opinion.

I used the more explicit table and column alias `p(name)` and the table-qualified reference `p.name` to defend against possible duplicate names. `name` is such a common word, it might also pop up as column name in the underlying table `band`, in which case it would silently resolve to `band.name`. The simple form `json_array_elements_text(people) name` only attaches a *table* alias, the column name is still `value`, as returned from the function. But `name` resolves to its single column `value` when used in the `SELECT` list. It ***happens to work as expected***. But a true column name `name` (if `band.name` should exist) would bind first. While that won't bite in the given example, it can be ***a loaded foot gun*** in other cases.

I wouldn't use the generic word "name" as identifier to begin with. Maybe that was just for the simple test case.

---

If the column `people` can hold anything but a plain *JSON array*, either query would trigger an exception. If you cannot guarantee data integrity, you might want to defend with [`json_typeof()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208521/3684):

```
SELECT p.name, count(*) AS c
FROM   band b, json_array_elements_text(b.people) p(name)
WHERE  json_typeof(b.people) = 'array'
GROUP  BY 1; -- optional short syntax since you seem to prefer short syntax
```

Excludes violating rows from the query.

Related:

- [When can we use an identifier number instead of its name in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596290/when-can-we-use-an-identifier-number-instead-of-its-name-in-postgresql/24596349#24596349)

Answer (score 7):

Based on **@ypercubeᵀᴹ** comment I ended up with :

```
SELECT name, count(*) as c
FROM band 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(people::jsonb) as name
GROUP BY name;
```

Just used `jsonb_array_elements` instead of `unnest`.

Answer (score -1):

For someone in MySQL

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(people, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')) AS name, count(*) as count
FROM yourtable
JOIN subtable AS indexes
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(people, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].id')) IS NOT NULL
group by name
```

with subtable like: Colum: idx, row: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...