# Trigger with IS DISTINCT FROM on rows with json/jsonb without comparison itemizing?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.6, json, plpgsql

Is it not possible to do a full row comparison in an INSERT/UPDATE trigger when the table has json or jsonb columns? The error I'm getting makes me think I'd need to individually compare each column because the `NEW.*/OLD.*` format can't be used to compare json columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_insert_update_modified()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) THEN
    NEW.modified_at = now();
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE
    RETURN OLD;
  END IF;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_insert_update
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_insert_update_modified();
```

When I insert into the table which contains json and jsonb columns, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = json
LINE 1: SELECT row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*)
                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function on_insert_update_modified() line 3 at IF
```

Is there a better way out of this?

Comment: `new is distinct from old` should work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Normally, yes. But ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Immediate problem: type `json`

There are no equality or inequality operators defined for the Postgres data type `json`. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296054/939860)
- [How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64759/how-to-remove-known-elements-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql/64765#64765)

Hence row comparisons involving a `json` column are also bound to fail - with notable exceptions, see below.

There are (imperfect!) workarounds, but don't bother and switch to **`jsonb`**, which allows these checks.

#### Fix function & trigger

You also cannot compare `OLD` and `NEW` for `INSERT` operations, where there is no `OLD` - only for `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. I suggest a column default for `modified_at`, or a separate trigger function and trigger `BEFORE INSERT` to overwrite any input with `now()` unconditionally.

And this function & trigger for `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_update_modified()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD THEN
      NEW.modified_at = now();
      RETURN NEW;
   ELSE
      RETURN NULL;  -- skip empty update, see below
   END IF;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_update  -- doesn't work!
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_js
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_update_modified();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0cd30fc4e5e52cce18c4abb47bea1415)* (Postgres 9.6)

Nothing different in Postgres 13: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0cd30fc4e5e52cce18c4abb47bea1415)*

`RETURN NULL;` is optional. If the row has not changed at all (and while running the trigger function already anyway) you might as well skip the `UPDATE` for the row if it does not change it. That save the considerable cost of writing a new row version in vain. If other triggers depend on it, or for other exotic edge cases, you may still want to go through with it. Then `RETURN NEW;` - unconditionally at the end of the trigger function. `RETURN OLD;` would have no benefit after we have established both row values are identical.

#### Row comparison with `json` column can still work?

Oddly, yes. Row comparison is processed left-to-right. For the expression `NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD` Postgres can return `true` immediately on finding the first mismatch (before encountering the problem with `json`). This may or may not happen, depending on the code path. [Quoting the manual on row-wise comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) :

> #### Note
>
> Errors related to the number or types of elements might not occur if the comparison is resolved using earlier columns.