# How to remove an element from a col with a CSV of ints in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-9.2, array

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 database and a table:

```
id integer,
allowed_types character varying(255)`
```

Sample data as below:

```
id  allowed_types
1   3,4,5,13,14
```

How I can remove *4* and *5* from `allowed_types` which is a comma separated varchar list?

**After removing, the result** should be `allowed_types = 3,13,14`.

There are many records on that table, each `allowed_types` could contain different numbers, separated by comma.

I considered [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) and [`array_remove()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html), but `array_remove()` is not in version 9.2, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proof of concept for regular expressions:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(',' || '3,4,5,13,14' || ',', ',(4|5)(?=,)', '', 'g'), ',');
```

Returns:

```
3,13,14
```

Pad commas to cover corner cases at begin and end. The regular expression `',(4|5)(?=,)'` explained:

`,` ... literal comma
`(4|5)` ... two *branches*: either 4 or 5
`(?=,)` ... [*positive lookahead*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE): next character is a literal comma

Would need a functional trigram index on `(',' || allowed_types || ',')` for good performance with big tables (only slightly bigger than a regular index due to the added commas). Details:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

***Or***, with a more sophisticated regular expression, you can work with the original column and a trigram index on just `(allowed_types)`:

```
SELECT ltrim(regexp_replace('3,4,5,13,14', '((,|^)(4|5))(?=,|$)', '', 'g'), ',');
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=f903a15d7bac7cb8f159c45ee32f65a0)*

But I expect the first solution to be faster: complex regular expressions are more expensive.

#### The according `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    allowed_types = trim(regexp_replace(',' || allowed_types || ',', ',(4|5)(?=,)', '', 'g'), ',')
WHERE  ',' || allowed_types || ',' ~ ',(4|5),';  -- here, plain comma is good
```

What I would really do:
Update to a current version of Postgres ([pg 9.2 reaches EOL Sept 2017](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)) and probably use a normalized 1:n design.

Comment: Thank you! This should work. Update will be later but data is required now...

Comment: I'v confused a bit but `SELECT trim(regexp_replace(',' || '3,4,5,13,14' || ',', ',(4|5),', ',', 'g'), ',')` returns `3,5,13,14`, not `3,13,14`: [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=bbaede8e48ef893868bcc31c8c3351ac)

Comment: @Abelisto: You are right, the answer (though accepted) had a bug. The regular expression "consumed" leading and trailing comma, so that consecutive matches would fail. I fixed it with a positive lookahead (available in pg 9.2) which does not consume the trailing comma.

Comment: @Zhlobopotam: Consider the update.

Comment: Actualy did not tested it yet. It seemed working. Thanks for fix.

Answer (score 3):

[Postgres 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) allows you to use string_to_array and unnest, you can use it to get the desired result.

> ```
> create table foo(id int, allowed_types varchar(256));
> insert into foo values (1, '3,4,5,13,14');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> with a as
> (
>     select id, unnest(string_to_array(allowed_types, ',')) elem
>     from foo
> )
> select id, string_agg(elem, ',')
> from a 
> where elem not in ('4','5')
> group by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | string_agg
> -: | :---------
>  1 | 3,13,14
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7a6e94977233b788c21ef7aae17b186a)*

Comment: Could we use `regexp_replace` function ?

Comment: DB design is debatable, but since it's a string, you'll want to use `string_agg()`. Also consider this [related answer about original order of elements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27287/3684).

Answer (score 2):

## [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) Extension

PostgreSQL ships with an extension that provides this and it's even faster than core array functionality on ints. You can use `string_to_array` and then `intarray`'s `-` operator. Click here for the docs on [`intarray` in 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/intarray.html)

Before we install `intarray`.

```
test=# SELECT ARRAY[3,4,5,13,14] - ARRAY[4,5];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] - integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY[3,4,5,13,14] - ARRAY[4,5];
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Install `intarray` and try again

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
CREATE EXTENSION
test=# SELECT ARRAY[3,4,5,13,14] - ARRAY[4,5];
 ?column?  
-----------
 {3,13,14}
(1 row)
```

So from varchar.

```
SELECT string_to_array(allowed_types, ',')::int[] - ARRAY[4,5] AS after_operation
FROM ( VALUES ('3,4,5,13,14') ) AS t(allowed_types);
```

## Other notes

I agree with @Erwin when he says you should probably use a normalized 1:n design. But even if you can't, it's very clear you do not want a csv in your column. Consider at least upgrading the type to `int[]`. This requires no change in schema and can be done very easily using

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ALTER COLUMN allowed_types
  SET DATA TYPE int[]
  USING string_to_array(allowed_types, ',')::int[];
```

Comment: Good option, but cannot  install anything in production environment. Thank you for normalization tips! It legacy db, so it was made long time ago. Time to fix it. Cannot upvote however (newby here). Take +1 from me

Comment: @Zhlobopotam it's called an extension, but it's part of PostgreSQL. It's shipped in Ubuntu as postgresql-contrib. Essentially, you can build it separately and it's not required but it's a core module.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use two regexp in a row that will take care of everything, without needing to have a functional index:

```
-- Your update
-- taking out two numbers (4 and 5) from any place in the string
UPDATE
    t
SET
    allowed_type = regexp_replace(regexp_replace(allowed_type, '^4,|,4(,|$)', E'\\1', 'g'), '^5,|,5(,|$)', E'\\1', 'g')
WHERE
    allowed_type ~  '^(4|5),|,(4|5)(,|$)'
RETURNING
    allowed_type ;
```

```
| allowed_type |
| :----------- |
| 3,13,14      |
```

See a step-by-step approach at  *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=ce262a1fff4f8d1437787f4f9fccf455)*

---

**Assumption**: your list contains numbers separated by commas, with no spaces (after or before commas, nor at beggining or end of string). The numbers need not be in any order, and they can be repeated (even if it doesn't probably make sense)

Comment: Interesting. However, regular expressions are comparatively expensive. I added another alternative with a single `regexp_replace` on the plain column to my answer.