# How can you replace the last occurrence of a character in a string (text column)?

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression, replace

Let's say I have a text field with this value in Postgres:

```
'bar$foo$john$doe$xxx'
```

I'd like to replace just the last occurrence of the dollar (`$`) character with another character, for example '-'. After the replacement, the contents of the field should be:

```
'bar$foo$john$doe-xxx'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Introduction:

This problem involves a bit of lateral thinking. The **last** occurrence of any character is also the **first** occurrence of that character in the string when it is reversed! All of the solutions (bar one) use this approach.

For all of the 5 solutions presented, we have the following (a fiddle with all the code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d16c7d8751944edf2eb7eb929b5519d7). An individual fiddle with each solution separately is included with each solution below):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  t_field TEXT
);
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` is only required by the 5th solution. Then we run the following queries to populate the table - the first record is the OP's own data - the rest is randomly generated!

OP:

```
INSERT INTO test (t_field)
VALUES ('bar$foo$john$doe$xxx');  -- OP's own data
```

Random data:

```
INSERT INTO test (t_field)
SELECT 
  LEFT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT), FLOOR(RANDOM() * (5 - 3 + 1) + 3)::INT) || '$' ||
  LEFT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT), FLOOR(RANDOM() * (5 - 3 + 1) + 3)::INT) || '$' ||
  LEFT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT), FLOOR(RANDOM() * (5 - 3 + 1) + 3)::INT) || '$' ||
  LEFT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT), FLOOR(RANDOM() * (5 - 3 + 1) + 3)::INT) || '$' ||
  LEFT(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT), FLOOR(RANDOM() * (5 - 3 + 1) + 3)::INT)
FROM 
  GENERATE_SERIES(1, 29999);  --<<== Vary here
   
--
-- For this fiddle, we only have 30,000 (29,999 + the OP's original datum) records 
-- (although relative magnitudes appear good), the individual fiddles use
-- 300,000. 
--
-- 300,000 appears large enough to give reliable consistent results and small 
-- enough so that the fiddle doesn't fail too often - rarely fails on 30k.
--
--
-- You can vary this number, but please consider using the individual fiddles for
-- large numbers of records so as not to hit the db<>fiddle server too hard!
--
-- The home test VM used 10,000,000 records - 16 GB RAM, 1 CPU, SSD
--
```

The solutions will be presented in order of performance. It was tested on both db<>fiddle and on a home VM (16GB RAM, SSD) with 10M records in the test table - don't try 10M on the fiddle! Each method is given a factor in terms of how much longer it took than the fastest on the VM.

In all cases, the desired result of `bar$foo$john$doe-xxx` is obtained for the OP's original data and the test queries (with `LIMIT 2` show that they are behaving as expected - i.e. replacing the last dollar (`$`) sign with a hyphen (`-`). You may vary this limit on the fiddle to check.

### 1: Postgresql string functions (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html)), uses [`OVERLAY()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/overlay-function.php), [`STRPOS()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php) AND [`REVERSE()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/reverse-function.php) (individual [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=74eaa65ccab0de227b094f50a01e86c9)):

```
SELECT
  t_field, 
  OVERLAY(t_field PLACING '-' 
    FROM 
      LENGTH(t_field) + 1 - STRPOS(REVERSE(t_field), '$')
         ) AS result
FROM test;
```

- Peformance: time for 10M records = 8034.787 ms.
- Comparison with fastest = **1.0 x**

### 2: Reverse() and the regex function [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) (individual [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c08c952b39e0175f062ea6b93d095466)):

```
SELECT 
  REVERSE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REVERSE(t_field), '\$', '-'))
FROM
  test;
```

What is being done (from the inside out) is:

- [`REVERSE()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/reverse-function.php) the string,
- run [`REGEXP_REPLACE('xxx', '\$', '-')`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) on the reversed string.

  Note that this will only replace the **first** instance of `$` because the `'g'` (global) flag isn't present - if the code read `... , '-', 'g')`, then **all** of the dollars would be replaced - and you can do that anyway with the (much cheaper) [`REPLACE()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/) function.

  Note also that `$` is a regex [`meta-character`](https://www.regextutorial.org/regular-expression-metacharacters.php) - i.e. it has special functionality within regular expressions (it means the last character of a string) and therefore it has to be escaped with the backslash (`\`) character when replacing it.
- then, the final step is to reverse our edited string back to its original order and we have the result!

It is worth bearing in mind that regular expressions are **incredibly** powerful. Unfortunately (paraphrasing), [with great power comes great complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_great_power_comes_great_responsibility). Regexes can become convoluted and difficult to understand very easily - but they are well worth dipping into - they can turn pages of code into one-liners in the hands of an adept!

It is always worthwhile trying to find a different solution with the non-regex functionality first (*c.f.* solution 1), but they have their place and in this case, it works reasonably well! [The site linked to above](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) is a good place to start exploring them.

- Peformance: time for 10M records = 14298.643 ms.
- Comparison with fastest = **1.77 x**

### 3: Alternative regex with REGEXP_REPLACE() (doesn't use REVERSE() - [see Evan Carroll's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303266/34007) (individual [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3713a6c1e2a94575f9cad43c4ae2beb6))):

```
SELECT
  t_field,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(t_field, '(.*)\$', '\1-' )
FROM test
LIMIT 2;
```

- Peformance: time for 10M records = 16316.768 ms.
- Comparison with fastest =  **2.03 x**

### 4: Alternative string function only, uses [`SUBSTRING()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php), [`POSITION()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-position/) and [`LENGTH()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-length-function/) (individual [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=40d459051a3467c2b6d3f6dfdd1ec18a)):

```
SELECT
  t_field,
  REVERSE(
  SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t_field) FROM 1 FOR POSITION('$' IN REVERSE(t_field)) - 1)
  || '-' ||
  SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t_field) FROM POSITION('$' IN REVERSE(t_field)) + 1 FOR (LENGTH(REVERSE(t_field)))))
 FROM test
LIMIT 2;
```

- Peformance: time for 10M records = 16316.768 ms.
- Comparison with fastest =  **2.34 x**

### 5: `ARRAY` ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html)) - v. slow but demonstrates [`STRING_TO_ARRAY()`](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_string_to_array-function.php), [`UNNEST()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-array/) and [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html)<sup>1</sup>  (individual [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cea5c6b2add8db5cc7daad0d45a55ff7))

<sup>1: See these posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number) & [3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)) by Erwin Brandstetter on `WITH ORDINALITY`</sup>

The individual fiddle shows a number of approaches together with performance analysis and some discusson. Included for completeness only and not, in this case, as a realistic choice.

Despite, in this particular case, the `ARRAY` technique is not very performant (by virtue of having subqueries), much of the backend code of the server uses `ARRAY`s and they can frequently be the optimum method to tackle various problems. It is **well worth** getting to know this little-known corner of PostgreSQL.

The first thing is to do this:

```
SELECT
  UNNEST
  (STRING_TO_ARRAY(REVERSE((SELECT t.t_field 
                                    FROM test t
                                    WHERE t.id = 1
                                    )), '$'));
```

Result (The OP's record - note `xxx` comes first because of the REVERSE()):

```
str
xxx
eod
nhoj
oof
rab
```

The string is split into fields by the `$` character.

Then:

```
SELECT
  t.t_field,
  t.id, x.elem, x.num
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
  UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(REVERSE((SELECT t_field 
                                  FROM test
                                  WHERE test.id = t.id
                                  )), '$'))
  WITH ORDINALITY AS x (elem, num) ON TRUE
  LIMIT 5;
```

Result:

```
             t_field    id    elem  num
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx     1     xxx    1
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx     1     eod    2
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx     1    nhoj    3
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx     1     oof    4
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx     1     rab    5
```

The reason that we need the `WITH ORDINALITY` is that without is, we can't distinguish between the 1st element of the string (i.e. the one that interests us) and the others `(elem, num)`;

Then, we do this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT t_field FROM test WHERE test.id = tab.id),
  REVERSE(
  (STRING_TO_ARRAY((SELECT REVERSE(t_field) FROM test WHERE test.id = tab.id), '$'))[1]
  || '-' || 
  STRING_AGG(elem, '$'))
FROM
(
  SELECT
    t.id, x.elem, x.num
  FROM test t
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(REVERSE((SELECT t_field 
                                    FROM test
                                    WHERE test.id = t.id
                                    )), '$'))
    WITH ORDINALITY AS x (elem, num) ON TRUE
) AS tab
WHERE tab.num > 1
GROUP BY tab.id
LIMIT 2;
```

Result:

```
             t_field    result
bar$foo$john$doe$xxx    bar$foo$john$doe-xxx
7a29f$d06f$20e$21f$1b1  7a29f$d06f$20e$21f-1b1  -- will vary by fiddle run!
result
bar$foo$john$doe-xxx
```

What this is doing is to aggregate the reversed string back to its original form using the `$` as the separator, but **EXCLUDING** the first element (`WHERE num > 1;`). In place of the first element is the first element - the array reference `[1]` + the hyphen (`|| '-' ||`) and so, we have `xxx-` plus the other elements of the reversed string with `$` separating them.

We then just simply apply `REVERSE()` to the whole construct to give the desired result!

- Peformance: time for 10M records = 80715.198 ms.
- Comparison with fastest =  **10.04 x**

There is a solution possible that doesn't use `WITH ORDINALITY` ([ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) instead) - see discussion in the individual fiddle.

### Performance

The performance figures on 10M records on a home VM are shown with each query - the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d16c7d8751944edf2eb7eb929b5519d7) (30,000 records) results mirror them fairly closely in terms of relative magnitudes.

So, in this scenario, use string based methods if possible, but regular expressions can help reduce the [SLOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) count, however they can be slower - it's up to the DBA/Dev to make that choice between speed and complexity.

Answer (score 8):

## Using [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

You can do this with a regex and a capture paren using [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(t.x, '(.*)\$', '\1-' )
FROM ( VALUES ('bar$foo$john$doe$xxx') ) AS t(x);
```

Will replace the last `$` with `-`. The end result is,

```
bar$foo$john$doe-xxx
```

Here is how it works,

- captures everything before the last `$` into `\1` and saves it.
- grabs but does not capture the last `$`
- leaves everything else...

Then it restores the capture with `\1` and adds a `-` leaving the rest of the string in tact.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another Option for you.
Admittedly, this one may or may not be relevant to your situation, but I'll mention it anyway, if only for completeness ...

Properly Normalise your Data to have only *one* value per field.
That way, changing any *one* value becomes Childs-Play.
It's just a *regular* update statement.

Caveat: If you ***never*** query your table using any *part* of this field's value, then this approach is [probably] overkill.